# General matrix Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, coordinate-systems, lorentz-symmetry

I just finished an introduction course into theory of relativity and am trying to find the general matrix Lorentz transformation. I have already looked into [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103560/), but I could not make much out of it.

Basically, we know that for one space vector relating a frame S and S':
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
ct \\
x
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & \gamma \beta \\
\gamma \beta & \gamma
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
ct' \\
x'
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
This I simplify to $x = L_1 x'$. My thinking therefore is that if S' moves from S in two space coordinates ($x$ and $y$), then I can use first move in $x$ and then in $y$, such that $x=L_1 L_2 x'$, where in $L_1$ I keep the $y$ coordinate fixed, and in $L_2$ I keep the x coordinate fixed. Writing this out would be:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
ct \\
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_x & \gamma_x \beta_x & 0\\
\gamma_x \beta_x & \gamma_x & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_y & 0 &\gamma_y \beta_y\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\gamma_y \beta_y & 0& \gamma_y\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
ct' \\
x'  \\
y'
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
ct \\
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_x \gamma_y & \gamma_x \beta_x & \gamma_x \gamma_y \beta_y\\
\gamma_x \beta_x \gamma_y & \gamma_x & \gamma_x \beta_x \gamma_y \beta_y\\
\gamma_y \beta_y  & 0 & \gamma_y\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
ct' \\
x'  \\
y'
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
To me all of this looks quite neat, but when I try to apply it to velocity addition, I get false results. As far as I could make it out, the zero in the last 3x3 matrix is wrong (,which won't disappear neither if I add a z coordinate as well... ).

I am therefore hoping that someone can indicate to me where I am doing something wrong when trying to create a more general lorentz matrix equation. I have found on [wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCIPX.png) a big matrix equation, but because it starts talking about rotations and so on, plus it doesnt show how the components are put together, I dismissed it for now.

(In case this is correct and my sense that I got it wrong is false due to the velocity addition method I apply, do let me know, and I can elaborate on that method as well. )

Comment: Classical Electrodynamics by J. D. Jackson outlines this. Basically, there is a single $\gamma$ and three components of velocity, and you must consider infinitesimal rotation matrices. Check this out: if your $L_1$ and $L_2$ don't commute, you're not doing the transform properly to get a general 3D result. And they don't commute.

Comment: The composition of two 1-space dimensional Lorentz transformations (obviously along the same axis)  is also a 1-space dimensional Lorentz transformation. But the composition of an 1-space dimensional Lorentz transformation along $\:x-$axis and  an 1-space dimensional Lorentz transformation along $\:y'\!-$axis is a 2-space dimensional Lorentz transformation plus a rotation.

Comment: @Frobenius, that actually makes sense. I'm just wondering how one would do a four dimensional rotation (in the case I would expand it to include the z coordinate as well).

Comment: ... the rotation is 2-dimensional in this case. I am preparing a new comment. Be patient.

Comment: In my answer as "user82794" therein : [Two sets of coordinates each in frames  OO  and  O′O′  (Lorentz transformation)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200844/two-sets-of-coordinates-each-in-frames-o-and-o-lorentz-transformation) and in **SECTION B** I produce a more general Lorentz Transormation from the 1-space dimensional one. My results are identical to those given without proof in "CLASSICAL ELECTRODYNAMICS" by J.D.Jackson, 3rd Edition , §§ 11.3.

Comment: \begin{align}                 
    \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & =  \mathbf{x}+(\gamma-1)(\mathbf{n}\cdot  \mathbf{x})\mathbf{n}-\gamma \mathbf{v}t
\tag{A-01a}\\
 t^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & =  \gamma\left(t-\dfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{x}}{c^{2}}\right)
\tag{A-01b}      
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{n}=\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{\Vert\mathbf{v}\Vert}$.

Comment: @Frobenius, thanks! I will study through it, but it looks promising!

Comment: @Frobenius, just reviewing back to my idea and your comment of having to add a rotation term: Don't I already take into account the rotation when defining the LT in y such that x remains constant? The way I put it together is using velocity addition, such that from a frame S to S' we move along the x-axis (an LT in x), then from S' to S'', where S'' moves in the y direction (and thus an LT in y). Since LT(S->S')LT(S'->S'') = LT(S->S''), I would have imagined my idea to be correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

From Figure 01 :

Lorentz Transformation from $\:\mathrm{S}\equiv \{xy\eta, \eta=ct\}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S_{1}}\equiv \{x_{1}y_{1}\eta_{1}, \eta_{1}=ct_{1}\}\:$
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_{1}\\
     y_{1}\\
     \eta_{1}
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & -\sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      -\sinh\zeta & 0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x\\
     y\\
     \eta
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \quad \tanh\zeta=\dfrac{u}{c}
\tag{01}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{X_{1}}=\mathrm{L_{1}}\mathbf{X}\,, \qquad \mathrm{L_{1}}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & -\sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      -\sinh\zeta & 0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{01"}   
\end{equation}

[image]

From Figure 02:

Lorentz Transformation from $\:\mathrm{S_{1}}\equiv \{x_{1}y_{1}\eta_{1}, \eta_{1}=ct_{1}\}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S_{2}}\equiv \{x_{2}y_{2}\eta_{2}, \eta_{2}=ct_{2}\}\:$
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_{2}\\
     y_{2}\\
     \eta_{2}
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  -\sinh\xi \\
     0 & -\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_{1}\\
     y_{1}\\
     \eta_{1}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \quad \tanh\xi=\dfrac{w}{c}
\tag{02}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{X_{2}}=\mathrm{L_{2}}\mathbf{X_{1}}\,, \qquad \mathrm{L_{2}}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  -\sinh\xi \\
     0 & -\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}  
\tag{02"}   
\end{equation}
Note that because of the Standard Configurations the matrices $\:\mathrm{L_{1}}, \mathrm{L_{2}}\:$ are real symmetric.

From equations (01) and (02) we have
\begin{equation}   \mathbf{X_{2}}=\mathrm{L_{2}}\mathbf{X_{1}}=\mathrm{L_{2}}\mathrm{L_{1}}\mathbf{X}\Longrightarrow \mathbf{X_{2}}=\Lambda\mathbf{X} 
\tag{03}   
\end{equation}
where $\:\Lambda\:$ the composition of the two Lorentz Transformations $\:\mathrm{L_{1}}, \mathrm{L_{2}}\:$
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=\mathrm{L_{2}}\mathrm{L_{1}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  -\sinh\xi \\
     0 & -\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & -\sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      -\sinh\zeta & 0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{04}   
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & -\sinh\zeta \\
     \hphantom{-}\sinh\zeta\sinh\xi   &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  -\cosh\zeta\sinh\xi \\
     -\sinh\zeta\cosh\xi & -\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{04"}   
\end{equation}

The Lorentz Transformation matrix $\:\Lambda\:$ is not symmetric, so the systems $\:\mathrm{S},\mathrm{S_{2}}\:$ are not in the Standard configuration. But it could be written as
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=\mathrm{R}\cdot\mathrm{L}
\tag{05}   
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathrm{L}\:$ is the symmetric  Lorentz Transformation matrix from $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ to an intermediate system $\:\mathrm{S'_{2}}\:$ in Standard configuration to it and co-moving with $\:\mathrm{S_{2}}\:$, while $\:\mathrm{R}\:$ is a purely spatial transformation from $\:\mathrm{S'_{2}}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S_{2}}$.

[image]

Now it's up to you to find the Lorentz Transformation matrix $\:\mathrm{L}\:$ first and then to prove that $\:\mathrm{R}\:$ is
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\color{blue}{\:\:\mathrm{R}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0 \\
     \sin\phi &\hphantom{-}\cos\phi & 0 \\
     0 & 0 &  1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \:\text{where}\:  \tan\phi =\dfrac{\sinh\zeta\sinh\xi} {\cosh\zeta+\cosh\xi}\,,  \: \phi \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)}\:\:\vphantom{\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{matrix}}}
   \tag{06}   
\end{equation}
representing a plane rotation from $\:\mathrm{S'_{2}}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S_{2}}\:$, see Figure 03.

---

**EDIT**

<sup>The Lorentz Transformation matrix $\:\mathrm{L}\:$, from $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ to the intermediate system $\:\mathrm{S'_{2}}\:$ in Standard Configuration to it, is :
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{x} & \left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{x}\mathrm{n}_{y} & \!-\dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{x}}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{y}\mathrm{n}_{x} & 1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{y} & \!-\dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{y}}{c}  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \!-\dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{x}}{c} & \!-\dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{y}}{c} &  \gamma_{\!\upsilon} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{07}   
\end{equation}
In (07) 
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\upsilon} & = \left(\upsilon_{x},\upsilon_{y}\right)
\tag{08.1}\\
\mathbf{n} & = \left(\mathrm{n}_{x},\mathrm{n}_{y}\right)=\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{\Vert\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\Vert}=\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{\upsilon}
\tag{08.2}\\
\gamma_{\upsilon}  & = \left(\!1\!-\!\frac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac12}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\!1\!-\!\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}}}
\tag{08.3}
\end{align}
where $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$ is the velocity vector of the origin $\:\mathrm{O'}_{\!\!2}\left(\equiv \mathrm{O}_{2}\right)\:$  with respect to $\:\mathrm{S}$, $\:\mathbf{n}\:$ the unit vector along $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$ and $\:\gamma_{\upsilon}\:$ the corresponding $\:\gamma-$factor.</sup>

<sup>The velocity vector $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$ could be expressed in terms of the rapidities $\:\zeta,\xi\:$ and so we could express the matrix $\:\mathrm{L}\:$ as function of them. To begin with this we first note that the velocity vector $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$ is the relativistic sum of two orthogonal velocity vectors $\:\mathbf{u}=\left(u\,,0\right),\mathbf{w}=\left(0\,,w\right)$ 
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\upsilon}=\mathbf{u}+\dfrac{\mathbf{w}}{\gamma_{\!u}}=\left[u\,,\left(\!1\!-\!\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{\!\!\frac12}\!\!w\right]\,,\quad \gamma_{u}  = \left(\!1\!-\!\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{\!\!-\frac12}
\tag{09}   
\end{equation}
not to be confused with the relativistic sum of two collinear velocity vectors pointing to the same direction
\begin{equation}
\upsilon \ne \dfrac{u\!+\!w}{1+\dfrac{uw}{c^{2}}}
\tag{10}   
\end{equation}
From (09) we have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\upsilon_{x}}{c} & = \dfrac{u}{\:\:c\:\:}=\tanh\zeta
\tag{11.1}\\
\dfrac{\upsilon_{y}}{c} & = \dfrac{w}{\gamma_{u}c}= \dfrac{\tanh\xi}{\cosh\zeta}
\tag{11.2}\\
\left(\dfrac{\upsilon}{c}\right)^{2}  & = \left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{x}}{c}\right)^{2}+\left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{y}}{c}\right)^{2}=1-\left(\dfrac{1}{\cosh\zeta\cosh\xi}\right)^{2}=\dfrac{\gamma^{2}_{\upsilon}\!-\!1}{\gamma^{2}_{\upsilon}}
\tag{11.3}\\
\gamma_{\upsilon}  & = \left(\!1\!-\!\frac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac12}=\cosh\zeta\cosh\xi
\tag{11.4}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{x}}{c} & = \sinh\zeta \cosh\xi
\tag{12.1}\\
\dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{y}}{c} & = \sinh\xi
\tag{12.2}\\
1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{x}  & = 1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{x}}{c}\right)^{2}}{\left(\dfrac{\upsilon}{c}\right)^{2}}=1\!+\!\dfrac{\gamma^{2}_{\!\upsilon}}{1\!+\!\gamma_{\!\upsilon}}\tanh^{2}\!\zeta=1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\zeta\cosh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}
\tag{12.3}\\
1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{y}  & = 1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{y}}{c}\right)^{2}}{\left(\dfrac{\upsilon}{c}\right)^{2}}=1\!+\!\dfrac{\gamma^{2}_{\!\upsilon}}{1\!+\!\gamma_{\!\upsilon}}\dfrac{\tanh^{2}\!\xi}{\cosh^{2}\!\zeta}=1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}
\tag{12.4}\\
\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{x}\mathrm{n}_{y} & =\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{x}}{c}\right)\!\!\left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{y}}{c}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{\upsilon}{c}\right)^{2}}=\dfrac{\gamma^{2}_{\!\upsilon}}{1\!+\!\gamma_{\!\upsilon}}\dfrac{\tanh\!\zeta\tanh\!\xi}{\cosh\!\zeta}=\dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}
\tag{12.5}
\end{align}
So the matrix $\:\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)\:$ of equation (07) as function of the rapidities $\:\zeta,\xi\:$ is
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\zeta\cosh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \!-\sinh\zeta \cosh\xi \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \!-\sinh\xi  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \!-\sinh\zeta \cosh\xi  & \!-\sinh\xi & \cosh\zeta\cosh\xi \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{13}   
\end{equation}
Now, in order to determine the spatial transformation $\:\mathrm{R}\:$ we have from (05)
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}=\Lambda\cdot\mathrm{L}^{-1}
\tag{14}   
\end{equation}
For $\:\mathrm{L}^{-1}\:$ equation (07) yields
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L}^{-1}=\mathrm{L}\left(\!-\!\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{x} & \left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{x}\mathrm{n}_{y} & \dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{x}}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{y}\mathrm{n}_{x} & 1\!+\!\left(\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{y} & \dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{y}}{c}  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{x}}{c} & \dfrac{\gamma_{\!\upsilon}\upsilon_{y}}{c} &  \gamma_{\!\upsilon} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{15}   
\end{equation}
and from (13)
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\zeta\cosh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \sinh\!\zeta \cosh\!\xi \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \sinh\!\xi  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
    \sinh\!\zeta \cosh\!\xi  & \sinh\!\xi & \cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{16}   
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & -\sinh\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \hphantom{-}\sinh\zeta\sinh\xi   &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  -\cosh\zeta\sinh\xi\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}} \\
     -\sinh\zeta\cosh\xi & -\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta\cosh\xi \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\zeta\cosh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \sinh\!\zeta \cosh\!\xi \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \sinh\!\xi  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
    \sinh\!\zeta \cosh\!\xi  & \sinh\!\xi & \cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{17}   
\end{equation}
Above matrix multiplication ends up to the following expression
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta\!+\!\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} &\!- \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} &  \hphantom{-} 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
    \dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \hphantom{\!-} \dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta\!+\!\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi} & \hphantom{-} 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
    0  & 0 & \hphantom{-} 1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{18}   
\end{equation}
But
\begin{equation}
\left(\dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta\!+\!\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}\right)^{2}+\left(\dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}\right)^{2}=1 
\tag{19}   
\end{equation}
so we can define
\begin{equation}
\cos\phi \stackrel{def}{\equiv}\dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta\!+\!\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}\,, \qquad \sin\phi =\dfrac{\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}\,, \qquad \phi \in \left(-\tfrac{\pi}{2},+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right)
\tag{20}   
\end{equation}
and finally
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0 \\
     \sin\phi &\hphantom{-}\cos\phi & 0 \\
     0 & 0 &  1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{21}   
\end{equation}
proving that $\:\mathrm{R}\:$ is a rotation, see Figure 03.</sup>

Comment: this is an amazing answer! Thanks for all the effort! I am able to follow you on everything. I am still struggeling though to understand why the rotation takes place (I know the math says so, but what does it say?). Is it because we try to align the x-axis to the direction the system S2 is moving away?

Comment: It's permissible to say that for the system $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ its axes are parallel to the axes of $\:\mathrm{S_{1}}\:$ and vice-versa because axes $\:x, x_{1}\:$ are collinear and $\:y, y_{1}\:$ are normal to the velocity vector $\:\mathbf{u}\:$. This is valid also between systems $\:\mathrm{S_{1}},\mathrm{S_{2}}\:$ since axes $\:y_{1},y_{2}\:$ are collinear and $\:x_{1}, x_{2}\:$ are normal to the velocity vector $\:\mathbf{w}\:$. But to say that $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ and $\:\mathrm{S'_{2}}\:$ are moving with parallel axes it's not permissible since has no sense.

Comment: This is due to the fact that a straight line rest in system $\:\mathrm{S'_{2}}\:$ oblique to the velocity vector $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$, as its axis $\:x'_{2}\:$ for example, is at any moment $\:t'_{2}\:$ a set of simultaneous events in $\:\mathrm{S'_{2}}\:$ but not simultaneous in $\:\mathrm{S}\:$. So for $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ there does not even exist any straight line, image of axis $\:x'_{2}\:$.

Comment: Right. That makes sense now. Thank you so much for all your effort! I will definitely go over this a few more times, but this is golden!

Comment: @Frobenius Hi, can you delete your previous comment, please, because they are off-topic.