# Can we decompose a general Lorentz boost in a rotation followed by three boosts along the coordinate axes?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, group-theory, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

$\newcommand{\betabold}{\boldsymbol{\beta}} \newcommand{\xbold}{\boldsymbol{x}} \newcommand{\ebold}{\boldsymbol{e}}$ For $\betabold\in \mathbb R^3$, with $0<|\betabold|<1$, let us denote the Lorentz boost with velocity $\betabold$ by 
$$
L^{\betabold}(t, \xbold):=\Big(\gamma t-\gamma \betabold\cdot \xbold, \xbold_\bot +\gamma \xbold_{\parallel}-\gamma\betabold t\Big), \quad \text{where }\ \gamma:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}.$$
Here $\xbold_\parallel:=\frac{\xbold\cdot\betabold}{\beta^2}\betabold$ is the component of $\xbold$ in the direction of $\betabold$, and $\xbold_\bot:=\xbold-\xbold_\parallel$. (The speed of light is normalized to $1$).

> Does there exist a spatial rotation $R$ and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3\in(-1, 1)$ such that 
>   $$
> L^\betabold = L^{\alpha_1\ebold_1}L^{\alpha_2\ebold_2}L^{\alpha_3\ebold_3}R\quad ?$$

Comment: A rotation can move any unit vector to coincide with any axis. So there exists a rotation which rotates $\mathbf \beta $ to the $\mathbf e_3$ axis. So yes; just look for such a rotation and then choose $\alpha_3 =|\mathbf \beta|$ and $\alpha_2=\alpha_1 = 0$.

Comment: @Dwagg: Don't you need a second rotation after the boost?

Comment: The commutator of two boost generators is a rotation generator. And you have $L^{\vec\varphi}=\exp(\mathrm{i}\vec\varphi\cdot \vec B)$, where $\vec B=(B_x,B_y,B_z)$ is a 3-tuple of boost generators. Your question is then if $L^{\vec\varphi}=L^{\alpha_1e_1}L^{\alpha_2e_2}L^{\alpha_3e_3}R$ for some appropriate $\alpha_i$ and $R$. The answer is yes because of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

Comment: Related : [General matrix Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361227/general-matrix-lorentz-transformation/361317#361317). By intuition there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain their reasons, please?

Comment: Elaborating an answer to your question first results show that my intuition  about infinitely many solutions is false. I could prove that for given $\:\boldsymbol{\beta}\:$  there exists one and only one triad  $\:\left(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\right)\:$ and consequently one rotation R satisfying your equation.

Comment: Elaboration is tedious and lengthy. But I'll post an answer in 2-3 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> \begin{equation}
> \mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\beta}\right) =\mathrm{R}^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\cdot\mathrm{L}_3\left(\alpha_3\right)\cdot\mathrm{L}_2\left(\alpha_2\right)\cdot\mathrm{L}_1\left(\alpha_1\right)   
> \tag{a}\label{a} 
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> \alpha_1 =\beta_1\,, \quad  \alpha_2 =\dfrac{\beta_2}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2_1}}\,, \quad \alpha_3 =\dfrac{\beta_3}{\sqrt{1-\left(\beta^2_1+\beta^2_2\right)}}
> \tag{b}\label{b}
> \end{equation} 
>    \begin{equation}
> \mathrm{R}=\text{space rotation} 
> \tag{c}\label{c}
> \end{equation} 
>   $==================================================$

[image]

[Figure-01 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycYUI.jpg)

From Figure 01 :

Lorentz Transformation from $\:\mathrm{S}\boldsymbol{\equiv} \{xyz\omega, \omega\boldsymbol{=}ct\}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S_1}\boldsymbol{\equiv} \{x_1y_1z_1\omega_1, \omega_1\boldsymbol{=}ct_1\}\:$
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_1\\
     y_1\\
     z_1\\
     \omega_1
   \end{bmatrix}
   \boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &-\sinh\!\xi \\
     0 & \hphantom{-}1 & \hphantom{-} 0 & 0\\
     0 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 1 & 0\\
     -\sinh\!\xi & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix} 
     x\\
     y\\
     z\\
     \omega
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \quad \tanh\!\xi\boldsymbol{=}\alpha_1\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{u_1}{c} 
\tag{01}\label{01}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{W}_1\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L_1}\mathbf{W}\,, \qquad \mathrm{L_1}\boldsymbol{=} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &-\sinh\!\xi \\
     0 & \hphantom{-}1 & \hphantom{-} 0 & 0\\
     0 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 1 & 0\\
     -\sinh\!\xi & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{02}\label{02}   
\end{equation}

Lorentz Transformation from $\:\mathrm{S_1}\boldsymbol{\equiv} \{x_1y_1z_1\omega_1, \omega_1\boldsymbol{=}ct_1\}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S_2}\boldsymbol{\equiv} \{x_2y_2z_2\omega_2, \omega_2\boldsymbol{=}ct_2\}\:$
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_2\\
     y_2\\
     z_2\\
     \omega_2
   \end{bmatrix}
   \boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &\hphantom{-}0 \\
     0 &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta & \hphantom{-} 0 & -\sinh\!\eta\\
     0 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 1 & 0\\
     0 & -\sinh\!\eta & \hphantom{-} 0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_1\\
     y_1\\
     z_1\\
     \omega_1
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \quad \tanh\!\eta\boldsymbol{=}\alpha_2\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{u_2}{c}  
\tag{03}\label{03}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{W}_2\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L_2}\mathbf{W}_1\,, \qquad \mathrm{L_2}\boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &\hphantom{-}0 \\
     0 &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta & \hphantom{-} 0 & -\sinh\!\eta\\
     0 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 1 & 0\\
     0 & -\sinh\!\eta & \hphantom{-} 0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{04}\label{04}   
\end{equation}

Lorentz Transformation from $\:\mathrm{S_2}\boldsymbol{\equiv} \{x_2y_2z_2\omega_2, \omega_2\boldsymbol{=}ct_2\}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S_3}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\{x_3y_3z_3\omega_3, \omega_3\boldsymbol{=}ct_3\}\:$
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_3\\
     y_3\\
     z_3\\
     \omega_3
   \end{bmatrix}
   \boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &\hphantom{-}0 \\
     0 & \hphantom{-}1 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-}0\\
     0 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta & -\sinh\!\zeta\\
     0 & \hphantom{-}0 & -\sinh\!\zeta &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_2\\
     y_2\\
     z_2\\
     \omega_2
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \quad \tanh\!\zeta\boldsymbol{=}\alpha_3\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{u_3}{c} 
\tag{05}\label{05}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{W}_3\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L_3}\mathbf{W}_2\,, \qquad \mathrm{L_3}\boldsymbol{=}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &\hphantom{-}0 \\
     0 & \hphantom{-}1 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-}0\\
     0 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta & -\sinh\!\zeta\\
     0 & \hphantom{-}0 & -\sinh\!\zeta &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta
   \end{bmatrix} 
\tag{06}\label{06}   
\end{equation}

Note that because of the Standard Configurations the matrices $\:\mathrm{L_1}, \mathrm{L_2},\mathrm{L_3}\:$ are real symmetric.

From equations \eqref{02},\eqref{04} and \eqref{06} we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{W}_3\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}_3\mathbf{W}_2\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}_3\mathrm{L}_2\mathbf{W}_1\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}_3\mathrm{L}_2\mathrm{L}_1\mathbf{W} \quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad \mathbf{W}_3\boldsymbol{=}\Lambda\,\mathbf{W}
\tag{07}\label{07}  
\end{equation}
where $\:\Lambda\:$ the composition of the three Lorentz Transformations $\:\mathrm{L_1}, \mathrm{L_2},\mathrm{L_3}\:$

<sup>\begin{align}
&\Lambda\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}_3\mathrm{L}_2\mathrm{L}_1\boldsymbol{=}
\nonumber\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
     1 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &\hphantom{-}0 \\
     0 & \hphantom{-}1 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-}0\\
     0 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta & -\sinh\!\zeta\\
     0 & \hphantom{-}0 & -\sinh\!\zeta &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta
   \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &\hphantom{-}0 \\
     0 &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta & \hphantom{-} 0 & -\sinh\!\eta\\
     0 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 1 & 0\\
     0 & -\sinh\!\eta & \hphantom{-} 0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta
   \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &-\sinh\!\xi \\
     0 & \hphantom{-}1 & \hphantom{-} 0 & 0\\
     0 & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 1 & 0\\
     -\sinh\!\xi & \hphantom{-} 0 & \hphantom{-} 0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{08}\label{08}    
\end{align}</sup>


<sup>that is
\begin{equation}
\Lambda\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}_3\mathrm{L}_2\mathrm{L}_1\boldsymbol{=}
 \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &-\sinh\!\xi\\
     \hphantom{-}\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\xi  & \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta & \hphantom{-}0 & -\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\xi\\
     \hphantom{-}\sinh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\xi & \hphantom{-}\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\eta &\hphantom{-} \cosh\!\zeta &  -\sinh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\xi\\
     -\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\xi &  -\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\eta &  -\sinh\!\zeta &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\xi
 \end{bmatrix}
\tag{09}\label{09}  
\end{equation}</sup>

The Lorentz Transformation matrix $\:\Lambda\:$ is not symmetric, so the systems $\:\mathrm{S},\mathrm{S_3}\:$ are not in the Standard configuration. But it's reasonable to suppose that 
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=\mathrm{R}\cdot\mathrm{L} 
\tag{10}\label{10}   
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathrm{L}\:$ is the symmetric  Lorentz Transformation matrix from $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ to an intermediate system $\:\mathrm{S'}_3\:$ in Standard configuration to it and co-moving with $\:\mathrm{S}_3\:$, while $\:\mathrm{R}\:$ is a purely spatial transformation between  $\:\mathrm{S'}_3\:$ and $\:\mathrm{S}_3$.

Now, our target would be to express the symmetric Lorentz Transformation matrix $\:\mathrm{L}\:$ in terms of the rapidities $\:\xi,\eta,\zeta\:$ since from \eqref{10}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}\boldsymbol{=}\Lambda\cdot\mathrm{L}^{\boldsymbol{-1}}
\tag{11}\label{11}   
\end{equation}

The Lorentz Transformation matrix $\:\mathrm{L}\:$, from $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ to the intermediate system $\:\mathrm{S'_3}\:$ in Standard Configuration to it, is :

<sup>\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{x} & \left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{x}\mathrm{n}_{y} & \left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{x}\mathrm{n}_{z} & \!-\dfrac{\gamma\upsilon_{x}}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{y}\mathrm{n}_{x} & 1\!+\!\left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{y} &\left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{y}\mathrm{n}_{z} & \!-\dfrac{\gamma\upsilon_{y}}{c}  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{z}\mathrm{n}_{x} & \left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}_{z}\mathrm{n}_{y} & 1\!+\!\left(\gamma\!-\!1\right)\!\mathrm{n}^{2}_{z} & \!-\dfrac{\gamma\upsilon_{z}}{c}  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \!-\dfrac{\gamma\upsilon_{x}}{c} & \!-\dfrac{\gamma\upsilon_{y}}{c} &\!-\dfrac{\gamma\upsilon_{z}}{c} &  \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{12}\label{12}   
\end{equation}
In \eqref{12}</sup>

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{c} & \boldsymbol{=}   \left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{x}}{c},\dfrac{\upsilon_{y}}{c},\dfrac{\upsilon_{z}}{c}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\left(\tanh\!\xi,\dfrac{\tanh\!\eta}{\cosh\!\xi},\dfrac{\tanh\!\zeta}{\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta}\right)\equiv \boldsymbol{\beta}\boldsymbol{=} \left(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\right)
\tag{13.1}\label{13.1}\\
\left(\dfrac{\upsilon}{c}\right)^{2}  & \boldsymbol{=} \left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{x}}{c}\right)^{2}+\left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{y}}{c}\right)^{2}+\left(\dfrac{\upsilon_{z}}{c}\right)^{2} \boldsymbol{=}1 \boldsymbol{-}\left(\dfrac{1}{\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}\right)^{2}=\dfrac{\gamma^{2}\!-\!1}{\gamma^{2}}
\tag{13.2}\label{13.2}\\
\gamma  & \boldsymbol{=} \left(\!1\!-\!\frac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac12}\boldsymbol{=}
\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \boldsymbol{=}\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3
\tag{13.3}\label{13.3}\\
\mathbf{n} & = \left(\mathrm{n}_{x},\mathrm{n}_{y},\mathrm{n}_{z}\right) \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}/c}{\upsilon/c}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\left(\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta ,\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta,\sinh\!\zeta\right)}{\sqrt{\cosh^2\!\xi\cosh^2\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta-1}}
\tag{13.4}\label{13.4}
\end{align}
where $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$ is the velocity vector of the origin $\:\mathrm{O'}_{\!\!3}\left(\equiv \mathrm{O}_{3}\right)\:$  with respect to $\:\mathrm{S}$<sup>(1)</sup>, $\:\mathbf{n}\:$ the unit vector along $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$ and $\:\gamma\:$ the corresponding $\:\gamma-$factor.

So the matrix $\:\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)\:$ of equation \eqref{12} as function of the rapidities $\:\xi,\eta,\zeta\:$ is<sup>(2)</sup>
 
<sup>\begin{align}
&\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}\left(\xi,\eta,\zeta \right)\boldsymbol{=}
\nonumber\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\xi\cosh^2\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} &\dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \!\boldsymbol{-} \sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^2\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta } &\dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \!\boldsymbol{-} \sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta } & \!\boldsymbol{-}\sinh\!\zeta   \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \!\boldsymbol{-}\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta  & \!\boldsymbol{-}\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta &\!\boldsymbol{-}\sinh\!\zeta &  \cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{14}\label{14}   
\end{align}</sup>

while

<sup>\begin{align}
&\mathrm{L}^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\boldsymbol{\upsilon} \right)\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{L}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\xi,\boldsymbol{-}\eta,\boldsymbol{-}\zeta \right)\boldsymbol{=}
\nonumber\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\xi\cosh^2\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} &\dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \! \sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^2\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta } &\dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \! \sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta } & \!\sinh\!\zeta   \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \!\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta  & \!\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta &\!\sinh\!\zeta & \cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{15}\label{15}   
\end{align}</sup>

From equations \eqref{09},\eqref{11} and \eqref{15}

<sup>\begin{align}
&\mathrm{R}\boldsymbol{=}\Lambda\cdot\mathrm{L}^{\boldsymbol{-1}}\boldsymbol{=}
\nonumber\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\xi & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &-\sinh\!\xi\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
     \hphantom{-}\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\xi  & \hphantom{-}\cosh\!\eta & \hphantom{-}0 & -\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\xi\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
     \hphantom{-}\sinh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\xi & \hphantom{-}\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\eta &\hphantom{-} \cosh\!\zeta &  -\sinh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\xi\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
     -\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\xi &  -\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\eta &  -\sinh\!\zeta &\hphantom{-}\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\xi\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
 \end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\ 
&\begin{bmatrix}
     1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^{2}\!\xi\cosh^2\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} &\dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \! \sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^2\!\eta\cosh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta } &\dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \! \sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 1\!+\!\dfrac{\sinh^2\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta } & \!\sinh\!\zeta   \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \!\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta  & \!\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta &\!\sinh\!\zeta &  \cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
   \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{=}
\nonumber\\ 
&\begin{bmatrix}
     \dfrac{\cosh\!\xi\!+\!\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\sinh\!\eta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\eta} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\dfrac{\cosh\!\eta\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\cosh\!\xi\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}  & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\eta} & \dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & 0   \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     0  & 0 & 0 &  1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
\end{bmatrix}   
\tag{16}\label{16}   
\end{align}</sup>


<sup>\begin{equation}   
\mathcal R=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \dfrac{\cosh\!\xi\!+\!\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\sinh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\sinh\!\eta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\eta} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\dfrac{\cosh\!\eta\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\cosh\!\xi\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta}  \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
     \dfrac{\sinh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} & \dfrac{\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\zeta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\eta} & \dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta}{1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
\end{bmatrix}  
\tag{17}\label{17}
\end{equation}</sup> 


<sup>\begin{equation}   
\mathcal R=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos\theta+(1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{x}^2 & (1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{x}\mathrm{m}_{y}+\sin\theta\mathrm{m}_{z} & (1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{x}\mathrm{m}_{z}-\sin\theta\mathrm{m}_{y}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
  (1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{y}\mathrm{m}_{x}-\sin\theta\mathrm{m}_{z}&  \cos\theta+(1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{y}^2 & (1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{y}\mathrm{m}_{z}+\sin\theta\mathrm{m}_{x}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}\\
  (1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{z}\mathrm{m}_{x}+\sin\theta\mathrm{m}_{y} & (1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{z}\mathrm{m}_{y}-\sin\theta\mathrm{m}_{x} & \cos\theta+(1-\cos\theta)\mathrm{m}_{z}^2\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{}}{\tfrac{}{}}}
 \end{bmatrix}
\tag{18}\label{18}
\end{equation}</sup>


<sup>\begin{align}    
& 2\cos\theta+1=\mathrm{trace}(\mathcal R)=
\nonumber\\
&\dfrac{\left(\cosh\!\xi\!+\!\cosh\!\eta\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\right)\!+\!\left(\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\!+\!\cosh\!\eta\!\cosh\!\zeta\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\cosh\!\xi\right)}{\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)}
\nonumber\\
&\dfrac{\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\right)\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\eta\right)\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\right)-\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)}{\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)}
\tag{19}\label{19}  
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
\cos\theta=\dfrac{\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\right)\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\eta\right)\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\right)-2\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)}{2\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)}
\tag{20}\label{20}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\cos\theta=\dfrac{\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\right)\left(1\!+\!\gamma_2\right)\left(1\!+\!\gamma_3\right)-2\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\right)}{2\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\right)}\,,\quad \gamma_{\jmath}=\left(1\!-\!\alpha_{\jmath}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-\frac12}}\:\: \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}} 
\tag{21}\label{21}  
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\sin\theta\,\mathrm{m}_{x} & =    \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\right)\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\zeta}{2\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)} 
\tag{22.1}\label{22.1}\\
\sin\theta\,\mathrm{m}_{y} & =   \boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\eta\right)\sinh\!\zeta\sinh\!\xi}{2\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)} 
\tag{22.2}\label{22.2}\\
\sin\theta\,\mathrm{m}_{z} & =   \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\zeta\right)\sinh\!\eta\sinh\!\xi}{2\left(1\!+\!\cosh\!\xi\cosh\!\eta\cosh\!\zeta\right)} 
\tag{22.3}\label{22.3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\sin\theta & =\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\right)^2\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)\!+\!\left(1\!+\!\gamma_2\right)^2\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)\!+\!\left(1\!+\!\gamma_3\right)^2\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)}}{2\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\right)} 
\nonumber\\
\gamma_{\jmath} & =\left(1\!-\!\alpha_{\jmath}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-\frac12}}\,,\quad \theta\in [0,\pi]
\tag{23}\label{23}  
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\tan\theta & =\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\right)^2\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)\!+\!\left(1\!+\!\gamma_2\right)^2\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)\!+\!\left(1\!+\!\gamma_3\right)^2\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)}}{\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\right)\left(1\!+\!\gamma_2\right)\left(1\!+\!\gamma_3\right)-2\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\right)} 
\nonumber\\
\gamma_{\jmath} & =\left(1\!-\!\alpha_{\jmath}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-\frac12}}\,,\quad \theta\in [0,\pi]
\tag{24}\label{24}  
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{m} & =\dfrac{\biggl[\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\right)\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\frac12}}\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\frac12}}\:\boldsymbol{,}\:\left(1\!+\!\gamma_2\right)\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\frac12}}\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\frac12}}\:\boldsymbol{,}\:\left(1\!+\!\gamma_3\right)^2\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\frac12}}\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\frac12}}\biggr]}{\sqrt{\left(1\!+\!\gamma_1\right)^2\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)\!+\!\left(1\!+\!\gamma_2\right)^2\left(\gamma_3^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)\!+\!\left(1\!+\!\gamma_3\right)^2\left(\gamma_1^2\!-\!1\right)\left(\gamma_2^2\!-\!1\right)}}
\nonumber\\
\gamma_{\jmath} & =\left(1\!-\!\alpha_{\jmath}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-\frac12}}\,,\quad \theta\in [0,\pi]
\tag{25}\label{25}  
\end{align}</sup>

$==================================================$

[image]
[Figure-02 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSGzg.jpg)

---

<sup>(1)
see [APPENDIX C - Relativistic addition of velocities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDsxD.jpg)</sup>

---

<sup>(2)
see [APPENDIX B - The matrix L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzXN5.jpg)</sup>

---

<sup>(3)
[Constructing $\:\boldsymbol{\alpha}\:$ from $\:\boldsymbol{\beta}\:$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIJGV.jpg)</sup>

---

Comment: Impressive. That's lots of work. It will take a while for me to digest it, but thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Frobenius Nice! One little question: What software/package are you using for the graph?

Comment: @J C :  GeoGebra. One of its advantages is inserting equations in $\LaTeX$.